# XSLT remove string from value with regex

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I would like to find and remove string from node value in XML using XSLT and regex:

```
<result>
   <item>
      <variantname>Apple 90 430 29 S</variantname>
   </item>
   <item>
      <variantname>Apple 90 480 29 M</variantname>
   </item>
   <item>
      <variantname>Carrot 60 420 27 M</variantname>
   </item>
   <item>
      <variantname>Carrot 60 440 27 S</variantname>
   </item>
</result>
```

I want to remove 430 and 480 from the XML above, the string between 'Apple 90' and '29'.

Output should look like this:

```
 <result>
       <item>
          <variantname>Apple 90 29 S</variantname>
       </item>
       <item>
          <variantname>Apple 90 29 M</variantname>
       </item>
       <item>
          <variantname>Carrot 60 27 M</variantname>
       </item>
       <item>
          <variantname>Carrot 60 27 S</variantname>
       </item>
 </result>
```

**Edit**:

I am just thinking that it is somehow possible to pass the "replaceable" string as variable?

removestarpartfromthis = "'Apple 90 * 29','Carrot 60 * 27'"

Comment: So where do the `27`s in the output `variantname`s for `Apple` come from? And what variation do you want to allow before and after the the asterisk, is that really literally `Apple 90` and `Carrot 60`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen this was a big typo, I updated the question + the comment with my little idea under Michael Kay's solution. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative it seems you could also just tokenize on whitespace and then remove the third token:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="variantname/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., '\s+')[position() ne 3]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to use a regular expression that lists part of the literal text you want to match and keep or remove then perhaps

```
  <xsl:template match="variantname/text()">
      <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '((Apple 90|Carrot 60)\s+)[0-9]+\s+(.*)', '$1$3')"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

gives you an idea. Online sample at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcop.

Comment: This is a nice solution too, but in this case I have items, where I don't want to remove the third part, this is why I am looking for a solution where I can specify the replaceable part.

Comment: @Adrian, I have added an example using replace and parenthesized subexpressions.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like

```
<xsl:template match="variantname/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'Apple 90 [0-9]+ 29', 'Apple 90 29')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This solution just works fine. In meantime I updated the question, it is possible to pass the replaceable part as a variable? I want to replace multiple items and if it is possible I want to avoid each replaceable item as a separate template.

Comment: Of course, XPath allows you to use an expression (such as a variable reference or a call on concat()) anywhere you can use a string literal.

Comment: Something is in my mind, but I don't really know how to do this right: <xsl:param name="values" select=" 'Apple 90 * 29','Carrot 60 * 27' "/> (where * is the delimiter), then something: <xsl:value-of select="replace(., $valuespartA [0-9]+ $valuespartB, $values)"/> ---> where $valuespartA is Apple 90 and $valuespartB is 29 and $valuespartA=Carrot 60, $valuespartB=27.